# proving with a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms, power-series

The question is :

> Show that if $n$ is a power of $2$, then $$\sum_{i=0}^{\log_2n-1}2^i=n-1\;.$$

Tried induction at first and tried to prove it on 2n but nothing came out of it.
Then i tried every possible way with a series and i'm close but still can't prove it.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You don’t need induction: it’s a straightforward calculation. If $n=2^m$, what is $\log_2n$?

Comment: Hint: Take a look at $\sum\limits_{i=0}^m 2^i$. Can you derive a closed form?

Comment: I can see how that works, it's the -1 in the log that bothers me, because i can't turn the log into m because if it... I know i'm missing something stupid... so embarrassing.

Comment: There is no $-1$ in the log: it’s to be read $(\log_2n)-1$. If the $-1$ were in the log, it would be written $\log_2(n-1)$.

Comment: Omg... So many hours on one stupid mistake... thank you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n$ is a power of $2$ then you have that $n=2^m$ for some $m \in \mathbb N$. Thus $$\log_{2}n=\log_{2} 2^m=m\log_{2}2=m$$ and therefore $$\sum_{i=0}^{(\log_2n)-1}2^i=\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}2^i=^{\text{Geometric sum}}=\frac{1-2^{m-1+1}}{1-2}=\frac{1-2^m}{-1}=2^m-1$$ but since $2^m=n$, the last term is equal to $n-1$.